# Dynamically building CAML query in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2010, caml

I have an requirement of get the items from the list depends on the ItemID.I have list which contains 5000 items in which I retrieve only 1000 items for that I will dynamically build the CAML query using JohnHoliday CAML.NET and the query have 1000 conditions at that time I got **Value does not fall within the Expected Range** error. The query works fine upto 150 items but it throws error when the ItemID increases.Could you provide a suitable workaround for this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running into the size limit for CAML queries, which AFAIK isn't documented anywhere, but definitly exists.

If you only need to support 2010 then you can use the new <In> operator which probably with get you a bid further

Answer (score 0):

In sharepoint 2010 there is a List view threshold configuration that give the administrator the ability to determine the maximum items you can retreive in a one patch
and to overcome this problem you can use
 `ContentIterator`
[check this link for more help](http://207.46.16.248/en-us/library/ff798376.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Why not iterate over SPList.Items and take which items you need? So there's no need to build a complex caml query. Or call SPList.GetItemByUniqueId.